# Women in xxx country are viewed as disposable/dispensable commodities

Tags: word-choice

> Women in xxx country are viewed as **disposable/dispensable** commodities

Which word is more appropriate? I see both in common use.

Comment: disposable means they can be used and then discarded. dispensable means they can be sold or traded cheaply.

Comment: @jlovegren: Um, I think dispensible is more likely to mean superfluous here. As in the country can get by without them. YMMV.

Comment: What @Tushar Raj said (which can be established using any dictionary). Which word to use depends on *exactly* what you want to say.

Answer (score -1):

A good word to describe that (heinous) situation is:

Women are *fungible* in {some country}.

Comment: "Fungible" means interchangeable, which is different from either disposable or dispensable.  Fungible commodities are often valuable.

Comment: Fungible means that one is as good as another.  It goes to the "commodity" meaning.  Something can be disposable or dispensable without being a commodity.

Comment: No, "fungible" means more than equivalent in value.  Fungible things are essentially identical.  For example, money (used as a medium of exchange, not collectibles) is fungible.  I doubt that even societies that treat women as commodities (i.e., as something to be bought and sold) regard them as identical.

Comment: To be *fungible* does not require that the items be *identical*, although an identical item would certainly be considered fungible; to be *fungible* something must be merely of the same type and of the same value.  One dollar or one dinar may be fungible  with another dollar or another dinar (money is the ideal fungible); but so may pack horses be fungible, or mercenary soldiers. It goes to *the value placed upon them*, and whether one is perceived to be a substitute for another.

Comment: Check a reference, say, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility.   The essence of fungibility is interchangeability, not value.  Obviously interchangeable things are of equal value, but the converse is not true.  But perhaps your use of "type and value" means that we're in violent agreement.